# Instagram API not fufilling count parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, count, instagram

The project can be viewed at http://watchsuburbia.com

I have a pagination gallery of Instagram images with a specific tag, but it is not loading more than 64 photos right now (was loading approximately 70 previously). If you go to [page 5](http://watchsuburbia.com/index.php?page=5), you can see it just stops abruptly. I have the **count** parameter in my URL and it's set to something high like 250 just to test, lowing it to something like 100 doesn't make a difference. There are *currently* 211 photos with the specific tag.

The url I'm using is

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/watchsuburbia/media/recent?client_id=[CLIENTID]&access_token=[ACCESSTOKEN]&count=300
```

*Obviously with real clientid and access_token*

**UPDATE** The limit has gotten even shorter again and is capping at 4 pages of photos now. It seems to get progressively lower every day which is extremely odd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What Instagram does is finds most recent X number of images you asked for (in this case, anything tagged #watchsuburbia) Then it checks if those are private, removes those and returns that subset. So if 3 videos out of that X are private, it'll actually return X-3 images.

What the [co-founder suggests](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/instagram-api-developers/nKik4i8OYhw) is that you look for more than you need as a buffer and filter it yourself.

Side note: everyone in those videos sounds *so Canadian*.

Comment: I'm not knocking your answer but I'm just adding this as a note for anyone else who stumbles on this... This suggestion breaks pagination. I.E - the method used to return the next X number of results assumes that you are displaying _all_ of those results. This leaves it to you to implement pagination and it's not immediately obvious how to pull the correct ID from the 'next' image you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

See [generic information on Instagram API endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/). It mentions the presence of a `count` parameter on the API requests... but does not list a specific maximum number. Perhaps Instagram is throttling the number of media in the result set -- hence the variation in result set size -- and they use the supplied `count` as a maximum value. Perhaps the actual maximum count depends per endpoint / type of object.

What you should do is use the numbers returned in the `pagination` hash in the result, and step through the results. The hash mentions a new value for the next maximum id (e.g., `next_max_tag_id` for tags or `next_max_id` for images) of the next page. Via that, you can retrieve subsequent result sets until no next results remain.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that the count parameters works in this endpoint (not yet?).
And the difference of media is because the count include private media I guess. You can see that in http://statigr.am/. their is the same difference.

Comment: It does work, because if I lower it to something like 5, it changes, but for some reason it's capping at a random number.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for surrian link, but I had the same problem and [solved it with pagination](http://plutov.by/post/instagram_api_count).