# Instagram API followers request returns ONE user

Tags: ajax, api, instagram

I setup a developer IG account, and am having a bit of trouble getting my user list. Every piece of data I try to grab only returns one result. I have over 100 followers and am following over 100 as well, but only one is returned.

I found this example where the user does a IG search. I try the same code with my access token (cannot use my id for some reason) and it does not work.
http://jsfiddle.net/z34bbb5r/

Really confused here. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I followed IG's instructions. Please help if you can!

**URL**

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/496457603/followed-by?access_token=XXXXXX

**Results**

```
{"pagination":{},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"username":"xxx","profile_picture":"https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/xxx.jpg","id":"xxx","full_name":"XX"}]}
```

Comment: May this can help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643830/using-the-instagram-api-to-get-all-followers